# Need to automate deployment of multiple Tomcats on single instance?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, puppet, configuration-management

Using which CM tool can we do the deployment of multiple tomcats on single instance.
Actually, I'm handling a pharmaceutical client, they have 5 products. We deploy multiple tomcats on a single instance all are running separate applications.

Just wanted to automate this deployment. Is there any configuration management tool available which can be used to deploy multiple tomcats with respective applications on a single instance.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Keep an eye out for Code Deploy and the others that AWS are bringing out of beta shortly. Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't do it. Separate them. I'm supporting two tomcat apps on one instance and have decided it was a bad idea. The biggest issue is health checks; ELBs can only do one health check. So if you need to kill an unhealthy instance and spin up a new one you have to kill all apps. In the cloud its better to have discrete services.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion Scott. But the client needs solid reasons as he's not technically sound. Also, we've seperate monitoring in place. I means we're using Pingdom for URL monitoring, OpsView and New Relic for Java based application monitoring so I believe health checks wouldn't be an issue here. :(

Comment: @ScottE you don't have to create an answer each time some add question in the comment. Update your previous answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks @btevfik, I'm still trying to get the hang of the stack exchange workflow. I agree neither post was a complete answer but rather they were intended to be helpful comments as I'm on my phone and justvtryingvto be helpful. I'll double check for comment option in the future.

Comment: Thank you as well @kkamilpl. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Well back to your question about a CM tool. I use Saltstack on this project and it works very well. With Saltstack I can easily manage the different configurations needed by the two Tomcat applications. But this is a fairly easy scenario for a CM tool and I think you could tackle this with any of the tools I'm familiar with such as Salt, Ansible, Puppet or Chef.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Atleast, now I know that it can be done. :) I'm from Infrastructure background and recently started my career in cloud. I don't know any CM tool, I need to learn it at the earliest and then implement it for the client, so which tool would you suggest to start with.                                           Thank a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Managing multiple tomcat instances is par for the course for any configuration management utility. For example, you could use puppet with [camptocamp's tomcat puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/camptocamp/tomcat). You can define multiple instances, each with their own configuration and applications.

In general, if you find yourself asking if puppet can configure something, do a search on [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/). The answer is probably that someone has already published a way to do it.